# Transferring Data From One Table to Another Using Multiple Keys in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, cursor, update, dictionary

I have data in one field and I want to transfer it to a specific field in another table based on specific keys Such as ID, road_type and veg_type.
My original table looks like this

```
ID  Road_Type    veg_type      DENSITY
1   1            A             5.26
2   2            B             2.12
3   2            A             .564
3   1            C             1.23
4   3            B             .5
5   2            B             1.5
```

The Transfer table will have each possible combination of Road_Type and veg_type as a field and I want the density value to be placed under the field based on the ID, Road and veg keys.

```
ID  R1_VA  R2_VA  R3_VA  R1_VB  R2_VB  R3_VB R1_VC R2_VC R3_VC
1   5.26   0      0      0      0      0     0     0     0
2   0      0      0      0      2.12   0     0     0     0
3   0      .564   0      0      0      0     1.23  0     0
4   0      0      0      0      0      .5    0     0     0
5   0      0      0      0      1.5    0     0     0     0
```

My code just gives me zeros

Here's what it looks like:

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*M'):

table1 = fc + 'table'
flds = ['ID', 'Road_Type', 'veg_type', 'DENSITY']

search_fc = {f[0:2]:f[3] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table1, flds)}

uc_flds = ['ID', 'R1_VA', 'R2_VA', 'R3_VA', 'R1_VB', 'R2_VB', 'R3_VB', 
         'R1_VC', 'R2_VC', 'R3_VC']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, uc_flds) as Cursor:
    for row in Cursor:
        ID = row[0]

        if search_fc.get(row[0]) == ID and search_fc[1] == '1' and search_fc[2] == 'A':
            row[1] = search_fc[row[0]]

        elif search_fc.get(row[0]) == ID and search_fc[1] == '2' and search_fc[2] == 'A':
            row[2] = search_fc[row[0]]

        #continue with elif statments for each field

        Cursor.updateRow(row)

        print str(row) +str(fc)
```

Is there anyway to fix it or is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Which ArcMap version do you have?

Comment: @BERA I have 10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By converting it to string I was able to get it to recognize the ID. 
Theres probably a much better way but this is what I got.

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*M'):

```
table1 = fc + 'table'
flds = ['ID', 'Road_Type', 'veg_type', 'DENSITY']

searchDict = {str(f[0])+','+str(f[1])+','+str(f[2]):(f[3:]) for f in 
arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table1, flds)}

uc_flds = ['ID', 'R1_VA', 'R2_VA', 'R3_VA', 'R1_VB', 'R2_VB', 'R3_VB', 'R1_VC', 'R2_VC', 'R3_VC']


print str(table1)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, uc_flds) as Cursor:
    for row in Cursor:
        ID1 = row[0]+','+ '1' +','+ 'A'
        ID2 = row[0]+','+ '2' +','+ 'B'
        ID3 = row[0]+','+ '3' +','+ 'C'
        ID4 = row[0]+','+ '1' +','+ 'B'
        ID5 = row[0]+','+ '2' +','+ 'C'
        ID6 = row[0]+','+ '3' +','+ 'A'
        ID7 = row[0]+','+ '1' +','+ 'C'
        ID8 = row[0]+','+ '2' +','+ 'A'
        ID9 = row[0]+','+ '3' +','+ 'B'

        if ID1 in searchDict:
            row[1] = searchDict[ID1][0]
        else: row[1] =0

        if ID2 in searchDict:
            row[2] = searchDict[ID2][0]
        else: row[2] =0

        if ID3 in searchDict:
            row[3] = searchDict[ID3][0]
        else: row[3] =0

        if ID4 in searchDict:
            row[4] = searchDict[ID4][0]
        else: row[4] =0

        if ID5 in searchDict:
            row[5] = searchDict[ID5][0]
        else: row[5] =0

        if ID6 in searchDict:
            row[6] = searchDict[ID6][0]
        else: row[6] =0

        if ID7 in searchDict:
            row[7] = searchDict[ID7][0]
        else: row[7] =0

        if ID8 in searchDict:
            row[8] = searchDict[ID8][0]
        else: row[8] =0

        if ID9 in searchDict:
            row[9] = searchDict[ID9][0]
        else: row[9] =0

        Cursor.updateRow(row)

        print str(row) +str(fc)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) module which is included in 10.5:

> pandas is an open source, BSD-licensed library providing
>   high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools
>   for the Python programming language.

```
import pandas as pd
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\table' #Change
fields = ['ID', 'Road_Type', 'veg_type', 'DENSITY']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields), columns=fields) #Create dataframe using da.SearchCursor
df2 = pd.pivot_table(data=df, values='DENSITY', index='ID', columns=['Road_Type','veg_type'], fill_value=0) #Pivot
df2 = df2.stack().unstack().fillna(0) #Add all possible columns even though value is missing, for example 'R1_B'
df2.columns = ['R'+'_V'.join(map(str, col)) for col in df2.columns] #Multilevel to one level and add prefix R and V
```

df2 is now:

```
    R1_VA  R1_VB  R1_VC   R2_VA  R2_VB  R2_VC  R3_VA  R3_VB  R3_VC
ID                                                       
1   5.26   0.0  0.00  0.000  0.00   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2   0.00   0.0  0.00  0.000  2.12   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3   0.00   0.0  1.23  0.564  0.00   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4   0.00   0.0  0.00  0.000  0.00   0.0   0.0   0.5   0.0
5   0.00   0.0  0.00  0.000  1.50   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Then you can do `df2.to_csv(r'C:\output\data.csv')` and [Table To Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm) to convert to the format you want